# Is the halting problem still an open problem?

Tags: solution-verification, fake-proofs, turing-machines

(Spoiler: Turing was right!)

I was thinking about Turing's proof that the halting problem is undecidable. But can the paradox, which is often given as a proof, be broken?

## Proof that a single program cannot decide the halting problem

First, I want to repeat the paradox in my own words:

Let `source` be the source code of a program, `args` some arguments to that program, and `eval(source, args)` an instruction that executes the program with the given arguments. Assume we had a program `will_halt(source, args)` that returns `True` if and only if `eval(source, args)` halts. Consider the program:

```
def p(source):
    while will_halt(source, (source)):
        pass  # endless loop
    return 42
```

`p` would run forever if `will_halt(source of p, (source of p))` returns `True`, and halts otherwise. `will_halt` is faced with a conflict for the input `(source of p, (source of p))`. Turing concludes, `will_halt` cannot exist, because for any program `will_halt` a program `p` can be constructed that creates a conflict.

## Resolving the conflict using two programs

`will_halt` must reason somehow whether loops terminate or not. It runs into a conflict for some inputs. However, we can define `will_halt_or_true` that returns `True` if and only if a conflict is encountered. Now, consider the following program:

```
def probe(source, args):
    while not will_halt_or_true(source, args):  # here we use 'not'!
        pass
    return eval(source, args)  # actually execute the program in question!
```

`probe(source, args)` behaves as follows:

| will_halt_or_true(source, args) | Conflict | eval(source, args) | probe(source, args) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | No | Halts | Halts |
| False | No | Runs forever | Runs forever |
| True | Yes | Runs forever | Runs forever |

We can use `probe` to distinguish the conflict from the non-conflict case. `will_halt_or_true(probe, (source, (args)))` returns `True` if and only if `eval(source, args)` halts. Note, that a single program running `will_halt_or_true(probe, (source, (args)))` is as powerful as running `will_halt_or_true` directly. So, the decision process always involves two steps and cannot be reduced to one.

## Conclusion (false)

My main argument is that no *single* program can decide the halting problem but *two* might. Knowing how `will_halt_or_true` handles conflicts enables us to construct a `probe` to decide the halting problem. This is by no means a proof that `will_halt` exists, but I argue that the "common" proof is not sufficient to claim that the halting problem is undecidable.

## Edit

I distinguished `will_halt` from `will_halt_or_true` to be more clear. However, I found the following counter example, which is quiet obvious:

```
def q(args):
    while will_halt_or_true(probe, (args, (args))):
        pass
    return 42
```

Any value contributed to `will_halt_or_true(probe, (source of q, (source of q)))` will lead to a contradiction. So, `will_halt_or_true(probe, ...)` cannot be used. Yesterday it worked ;-)

Comment: Excellent. Now, your job is to find the mistake(s) in your argument.

Comment: [**Halting problem proofs refuted on the basis of software engineering**](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/361701808_Halting_problem_proofs_refuted_on_the_basis_of_software_engineering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your approach, the assumption on will_halt that you start out with "Assume we had a program will_halt(source, args) that returns True if eval(source, args) halts and False otherwise." does not hold anymore: there are cases where evaluating source runs forever, but your will_halt returns True. So, whatever you do afterwards does not address the halting problem anymore, because that starts out with your (original) assumptions.

(As an aside, note that it is trivial to write a will_halt function that returns True if the eval(source,args) terminates and without restriction on the return value if eval(source,args) does not terminate. It's useless, though.)

Comment: The extended version of `will_halt` can be used unambiguously to decide whether a program halts or not. It is more powerful than a program that always returns `True`. `{ (q, args) | will_halt(probe, (q, (args)) }` is the complete class of programs that will halt for `args`. The program that combines `will_halt` and `probe` is a valid program. It is just not more useful than `will_halt` itself.

Comment: @Marian "The extended version of will_halt can be used unambiguously to decide whether a program halts or not." This statement is not consistent with the (two) tables in your question: look at the first and thirds columns. It should be true, because it's the assumption you make on will_halt, but your modified version doesn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: I edited my question to be more precise. ..., which does not change that you are right :-)